# grep php output show more than grep query

Tags: php, grep

I'm having an issue where `php file | grep "query"`'s output shows EVERYTHING, not just the grep'd output.

EX:

```
php /vagrant/code/test.php | grep "Do not show anything"
```

Shows anything echo'd in the php.

Displays whole output no matter what.

Final goal:

Find register_globals using this method.

Comment: Could be php prints to stderr instead of stdout (witch the pipe should swallow and pass to grep). Make sure php prints it's output to stdout. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: You just need to redirect stderr: `php /vagrant/code/test.php 2>/dev/null`. This way, just standard output will be sent to the next pipe.

Comment: How do I grep the stderr?